# Watson Text to Speech API. Getting invalid syntax in one of the API files

Tags: ibm-watson

I'm using Python 2.7.15 and I'm getting this message about one of the API files.
Any ideas as to what is going on.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "text_to_speech_v1.py", line 4, in <module>
    from ibm_watson import TextToSpeechV1
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ibm_watson/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from ibm_cloud_sdk_core import IAMTokenManager, DetailedResponse, BaseService, ApiException
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .base_service import BaseService
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ibm_cloud_sdk_core/base_service.py", line 136
    response = requests.request(**request, cookies=self.jar, **kwargs)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Can you provide more details? Like which API call and also the code snippet you are using to call the API endpoint

Comment: Actually it's resolved. It was a setup issue on my part. Thanks for the help.